# 'frameInterval' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: preferredFramesPerSecond

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-ios-build

I have a flutter app, a couple of weeks back I updated my Xcode version to 13.3 and now I'm facing an issue with my running flutter app while creating an Archive in xcode.

Error: 'frameInterval' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: preferredFramesPerSecond
Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')

Can anyone help me,how to fix this issue?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete you Pod file Using this command line syntax

```
rm ios/Podfile && flutter build ios
```

then you can get all you Xcode or swift supported pod file of dependency.